# Child component will only re-render when Parent component's button, Submit, is clicked twice

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have two components that I am having this issue with. The parent component, CustomerTableTools, is sends the size of the table (page) to the child component (FetchCustomerTable). The state of the Parent will change when I click Submit, but the child will not re-render unless I click Submit twice. The input and the Submit button are inside the parent, the table is inside the child. Am I missing an important detail here? I thought that the Child was supposed to re-render if the Parent sends its state to it as props and there is a State change.

The table's data is populated by this.props.customers
Thank you everyone for your time. I only want to learn, and I appreciate the input, thanks.

```
//***************************
//CustomerTableTools (Parent):
//****************************

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FetchCustomerTable from './FetchCustomerTable'
import LoadingSpinner from '../Util/LoadingSpinner'
import ErrorStatus from '../Util/ErrorStatus'
import axios from "axios/index";

class CustomerTableTools extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        limitChanged: false,
        page: 0,
        limit: 10,
        value: 10,
        customers: [],
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    console.log("props: "+JSON.stringify(props))
}


handleChange(event) {
    if(event.target.value >= 0 && (!isNaN(event.target.value) &&     
(function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; })(parseFloat(event.target.value)))) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
     }
}



componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({limit: this.state.value, limitChanged: true});

    console.log("Fetching data1");
    this.setState({loading: true, statusMessage: <LoadingSpinner/>});

    axios.get("http://localhost:8090/customer/viewCustomers/", {
        params: {
            page: this.state.page,
            limit: this.state.limit
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            // console.log("response: "+JSON.stringify(response.data));
            this.setState({
                customers: response.data.content,
                statusMessage: null,
                loading: false
            });
            console.log(this.state.customers);
        })
        .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({
                    statusMessage: <ErrorStatus error={error.toString()}/>,
                })
            }

        );

}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({limit: this.state.value, limitChanged: true});

    console.log("=====HANDLE SUBMIT=====");
    this.setState({loading: true, statusMessage: <LoadingSpinner/>});

    axios.get("http://localhost:8090/customer/viewCustomers/", {
        params: {
            page: this.state.page,
            limit: this.state.limit
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            // console.log("response: "+JSON.stringify(response.data));
            this.setState({
                customers: response.data.content,
                statusMessage: null,
                loading: false
            });
            console.log(this.state.customers);
        })
        .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({
                    statusMessage: <ErrorStatus error={error.toString()}/>,
                })
            }

        );
}



render() {

    let tableBody = null;
    tableBody = <FetchCustomerTable customers={this.state.customers}/>

    return(
        <div>
            <div id="grid">
                <div id="item2">

                    <form style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0}} 
                        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>
                            <div>Page Size:</div>
                            <input style={{width: '7vh'}} type="number" 
                               value={this.state.value} onChange= 
                               {this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            {tableBody}
        </div>
    );
}
}
    export default CustomerTableTools

//***************************
//FetchCustomerTable (Child):
//***************************

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../../App.css'
import LoadingSpinner from '../Util/LoadingSpinner'
import ErrorStatus from '../Util/ErrorStatus'
import {BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn, ClearSearchButton} from 'react- 
bootstrap-table';
import {Button, Glyphicon} from 'react-bootstrap'


class FetchCustomerTable extends Component {

onAfterSaveCell(row) {
    const customerId = row['customerId'];
    axios({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: `http://localhost:8090/customer/updateCustomer/${customerId}`,
        data: JSON.stringify(row),
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
    })
        .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            //logger.error(error);
        });
}

handleDeletedRow(rowKeys) {
    console.log("KEYS DROPPED: "+ rowKeys);
    axios({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: `http://localhost:8090/customer/deleteCustomers/${rowKeys}`,
        data: rowKeys,
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            //logger.error(error);
        });

}

//Style delete button on top of table
customDeleteButton = (onBtnClick) => {
    return (
        <Button onClick={ onBtnClick }><Glyphicon glyph="remove" /> Delete 
Selected</Button>
    );
}

onSearchChange = (searchText) => {
    console.log("inside search change!");
    this.setState({searchText: searchText});

}

handleClearButtonClick = (onClick) => {
    if(!!this.state.searchText) {
        console.log("Fetching data2");
        //this.setState({loading: true, statusMessage: <LoadingSpinner/>});

        axios.get("http://localhost:8090/customer/searchResults/", {
            params: {
                firstName: this.state.searchText,
                email: this.state.searchText,
                page: this.props.page,
                limit: this.props.limit,

            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("respsonse: 
"+JSON.stringify(response.data.pageable));
                this.setState({
                    //loading: false,
                    customers: response.data.content,
                    statusMessage: null
                })

                console.log(this.state.customers);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.setState({
                        statusMessage: <ErrorStatus error= 
                                       {error.toString()}/>,
                    })
                }
            );
        onClick();
    } else {
        //TODO: add method to clear search results
    }
}

createCustomClearButton = (onClick) => {
    return (
        <ClearSearchButton
            btnText='Submit'
            btnContextual='btn-warning'
            className='my-custom-class'
            onClick={ e => this.handleClearButtonClick(onClick) }/>
    );
}

render() {
    let content = null;

    //settings for BootStrapTable
    const options = {
        defaultSortName: 'customerId',  // default sort column name
        defaultSortOrder: 'asc',  // default sort order
        afterDeleteRow: this.handleDeletedRow,
        deleteBtn: this.customDeleteButton,
        onSearchChange: this.onSearchChange,
        clearSearch: true,
        clearSearchBtn: this.createCustomClearButton,
        pagination: true,
        nextPage: 'Next',
    };

    const selectRow = {
        mode: 'checkbox'
    };

    const cellEditProp = {
        mode: 'dbclick',
        blurToSave: true,
        afterSaveCell: this.onAfterSaveCell  // a hook for after saving 
                                                cell
    };

    const fetchInfo = {
        dataTotalSize: 100, // or checkbox
    };

    content =
    <div className="tableContainer">
      <BootstrapTable remote={ true } search={ true } striped 
      bordered condensed hover headerStyle={{ fontFamily: 'proxima-                      
                                             nova' }}
      bodyStyle={{ fontFamily: 'proxima-nova' }} 
      data={ this.props.customers } options={ options }
      cellEdit={ cellEditProp } selectRow={selectRow} deleteRow>
        <TableHeaderColumn name='customerId' dataField='customerId' 
          isKey dataSort>Customer ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn name='lastName' dataField='lastName' 
          dataSort>Last Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn name='firstName' dataField='firstName' 
          dataSort>First Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn name='email' dataField='email' 
          dataSort>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn name='address' dataField='address' 
          dataSort>Address</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn name='city' dataField='city' 
          dataSort>City</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn name='state' dataField='state' 
          dataSort>State</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn name='zip' dataField='zip' 
          dataSort>Zip</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn name='lastEmailSent' 
          dataField='lastEmailSent' dataSort editable={ false }>Last Email 
          Sent</TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
    </div>


    return(
        <div>
            <div className="center">
                {content}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default FetchCustomerTable
```

Comment: this might or might not be related to your problem, but you shouldn't call `this.setState()` the way you're doing it at the top of `componentDidMount` and `handleSubmit`. Instead combine the first 2 `setState`s in a single call and avoid an unnecessary re-renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this is for whoever is reading this. I was able to solve my issue by removing the extra unnecessary state 'value'. I made a FormControl select and have the user pick from a list of predefined page sizes rather than typing in the page size. The name of this picker is 'limit' which is the same name as the state representing the page size. I have a handler that updates this state whenever an option from the select is chosen.

Comment: That would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `componentWillReceiveProps` from life cycle of React in `Child` component.
https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I made a state inside the child Component  called customers and had it set using componentWillReceiveProps. I then made the table accept this child state Customers. The result was it now takes three clicks to get the table to re-render. Still not sure what  exactly is the issue